# WooCommerce custom mail different price than the customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, mollie

I am buying  products with 20% discount and resell them for a normal price on my website. 
I want to make a extra email that has to be send to my own email address when a customer makes a order on my website.

My question: 
If it’s possible to make a new email that will send the normal payment details but also the payed price with the 20% discount on it.

This will help me a lot to buy the products with the discount price so I can send the email to the product owner. Right now I have to calculate the 20% of the normal price and send that to the product owner.

Does anyone have a solution or a tip?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: answering your answer: yes, it's possible and have a lot of solutions. but you need to provide more info, such as the code you tried with errors

Comment: Can you send me 1 of the solutions? I haven't tried any code but I can't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_email_order_details` action hook, targeting "New Order" email notification (send to admin), where you will add those details this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'new_order_custom_email_notification', 20, 4 );
function new_order_custom_email_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email )
{
    // Only for  "New order" email notifications (admin)
    if( $email->id != 'new_order' ) return;

    $order_total = floatval($order->get_total());
    $order_total_discount =  $order_total * 0.2;
    $order_total_discounted =  $order_total - $order_total_discount;

    // CSS style
    $styles = '<style>
        .discount-info table{width: 100%; font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; margin-bottom:8px;}
        .discount-info table th, table.tracking-info td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px;
            color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px; width:58%;}
        .discount-info table td{text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;}
    </style>';

    // HTML Structure
    $html_output = '<h2>'.__('Reseller discount Information').'</h2>
    <div class="discount-info">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
            <tr>
                <th>' . __('Order total') . '</th>
                <td>' . wc_price($order_total) . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>' . __('Discount 20%') . '</th>
                <td>' . wc_price($order_total_discount) . '</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>' . __('Order total discounted') . '</th>
                <td>' . wc_price($order_total_discounted) . '</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div><br>'; // HTML (end)

    // Output CSS + HTML
    echo $styles . $html_output;
}
```

This will output something like:

[image]

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> To display it before Order details you can change the hook priority from `20` to `9`

Comment: Yes this helped me! Thanks alot :)